# Switch input stream in lex and yacc 

Tags: yacc, lex

I insist on using lex and not the flex.

am developing an API in lex like the one existing in the flex util ( yy_switch_buffer, yy_create_buffer ...) offering the possibility to switch between multiple buffers .

This is the main difficulty for me until now :

- for example when I encounter a `#include` token i should switch the buffer to the included file. So first i should interrupt the current parsing action( I tried `fclose(yyin)` FAILED) the parser complete the whole current yyin. NOT good because I should parse the included file to store structures (for example ) used in the main file.

Question is : How can I interrupt immediately a parser ? Is it enough for me to define a new buffer using `yyin = fopen(somefile, "r");` ??

Comment: Why do you need to go through the pain of reimplementing what is already implemented elsewhere?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i don't have the choice, am developing my solution for multiple platform(solaris, aix, win) and for some of them we can't install flex because the native lex existing solution may encounter problems.

Comment: That makes little sense.  The native `lex` may have problems, so you must use it?  You could compile with `flex` on one machine and simply compile the Flex library (`-lfl`) on the native machine, plus the transferred C source generated from the Flex.  But `flex` can be transported to those machines trivially.  There is no 'native Lex' on Windows.  You can either use MKS Lex & Yacc or Cygwin with Flex (and Bison if you need grammars too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to be tough to handle it, if it is doable at all.  AFAIK, Lex only allows you to switch input streams on EOF (real or simulated) when it calls `yywrap()`.

Maybe you can fake things so that when you find the 'include' directive, you fake an EOF on the current stream and then have `yywrap()` fix things so that the new input comes from the included file, and then when you reach EOF on the included file, you have `yywrap()` restore input from the original input stream at the original position.  Clearly, this works for nested includes (if it works at all) unless you arbitrarily restrict the number of levels of inclusion.

Comment: yes, I have prepared something for the problem of the parsing recovery of the main file after the parsing of the included file using the yylineno: number of line of the reached #include directive.

Comment: can yylex() simulate for me an end of file ?? it will be simple if i can manipulate the return value of yylex ?

Comment: You'd futz with the `input()` function, IIRC.  You can do that in Lex; you can't in Flex.  So, your rewritten `input()` function would have to take commands from the controlling code about when to return EOF.  The `yywrap()` code would also synchronize with the controlling code.  The `yylex()` is generated, of course, but you get to play with the actions after recognizing patterns, or your (separate) grammar can say "OK - got include; switch input files pro tem" by calling the appropriate support function(s) which commands the Lex support code to do what you need.

Comment: nice approach Jonathan, I'll do my best.Thinks to you

Comment: Actually, you can't portably futz with `input` -- it might be a macro or might be a function and might be intricately intertwined with the internals of the scanner.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: If this was Flex, you'd be right.  If this is AT&T Lex, then `input()` is a macro that can be undefined or redefined.  If the Lex on the systems of concern (AIX, Solaris, ... Windows) is not very close to the AT&T Lex, then you may have problems.  But the question explicitly ruled out consideration of Flex (which leaves open what is used on Windows).  It is slightly edgy territory; if you have an alternative suggestion, go ahead and quote it.  (POSIX doesn't give you permission to futz with `input()`; the original Lex article did.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no portable way to do this with POSIX lex -- different implementations have different internal arrangements of how they deal with and buffer input, and during lexing, may have read ahead of the currently processing token and buffered a bunch of the input.  So you need to get it to save what it has currently buffered and switch to a different input, and then restore the buffered stuff (so it will be read next) after you're done with the #include or whatever.  This is precisely what flex's buffer management calls are for, but if you insist on using lex, you'll need to (effectively) port these routines to understand the internals of whatever versions of lex you need to support.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the "included input files" is part of flex documentation, which provides an example how to switch between flex inputs ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_mono/flex.html#SEC12   ("Multiple Input Buffers")

Answer (score 0):

You can find flex tool ported to windows system here http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/